# TypeScript mixin extends other mixin: inconsistent "conflicting declarations" error

Tags: typescript, mixins, typescript2.8

I want to write two mixin classes, `Foo` and `Bar`.  `Bar` requires access to the protected interface of `Foo`.  Therefore I use TS2.8 conditional types to extract the type of a `Foo` class and use this type as a generic constraint for the `Bar` mixin's `Base` class.

Unfortunately, this causes mysteriously inconsistent "conflicting declaration" errors.  Why?  Is this a TS bug?  Can I work around it?

```
/*
* Why is this type error happening?
*   Class 'Composed' incorrectly extends base class 'Bar...
*     Type 'Composed' is not assignable to type 'Bar...
*       Property '_referenceToEmptyInterface' has conflicting declarations and is inaccessible in type 'Composed'.
*/
class Composed extends BarMixin(FooMixin(EventEmitter)) {}

import { EventEmitter } from "events";
type Constructor<I = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => I;

interface EmptyInterface {}

/** Mixin */
function FooMixin<C extends Constructor>(Base: C) {
    return class extends Base {
        private _referenceToEmptyInterface: EmptyInterface = {}; // Causes the error.  Why?
        private _fooPrivate: number = 0; // Does not cause an error.  Why not, given the above?
        protected _fooProtected: number = 0;
    }
}

/** Type of class that creates instances of type Foo */
type FooConstructor = typeof FooMixin extends (a: Constructor) => infer Cls ? Cls : never;

/** Mixin that can only extend subclasses of Foo */
function BarMixin<C extends FooConstructor>(Base: C) {
    return class extends Base {
        barMethod() {
            // We require `Base` to implement `Foo` because we need access to protected `Foo` properties.
            this._fooProtected++;
        }
    }
}
```

`_referenceToEmptyInterface` is flagged as a duplicate declaration.  However, `_fooPrivate` is not.  The only difference is that the former's type refers to an interface declaration, whereas the latter's type is a primitive.  The interface declaration is totally empty and is declared outside of the mixin function, so all declarations of `_referenceToEmptyInterface` should be identical.

Is this a bug in the compiler?  How should I handle this situation?

EDIT: related GH issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22845

Comment: Seems to be bug. Create an issue at typescript repo, interesting to see what they will tell.

Comment: What version are you using ? With 2.8 rc I get errors on compilation on ALL private/protected properties. (edited for brevity) : `Property '_referenceToEmptyInterface/_fooPrivate/_fooProtected' of exported class expression may not be private or protected.` These errors do not show in the editor but do show un in the output. My guess is the other error is just a side effect of these errors

Comment: Are you sure?  I wasn't able to reproduce that behavior.  I just tried with TS 2.8-rc.  I get the error for `_referenceToEmptyInterface`, but when I uncomment that line, I don't get any errors for `_fooPrivate` or `_fooProtected`.  The difference seems to be if the private / protected property refers to a primitive type (no error) or some form of interface (error)